# unable to extract meta keyword value from website using get_meta_tags() 

Tags: php

for example

```
$all_meta=get_meta_tags($website_name);
$keyword_meta=$all_meta['keywords'];
print_r($all_meta);
```

`print_r($all_meta)` only returns keywords from web page containing exactly the word 'keywords'...But few web-pages contain meta information in 'Keywords'...Can u tell me how to extract keywords which is independent of case?

---

take case of website-"http://www.microsoft.com"

$all_meta=get_meta_tags("www.microsoft.com");
$keyword_meta=$all_meta['Keywords'];
$keyword_meta1=$all_meta['keywords'];

print_r($keyword_meta);                    //shows error

print_r($keyword_meta1);                   /*displays Microsoft, product, support, help, *training, Office, Windows, software, download, trial, preview, demo,  business, security, *update, free, computer, PC, server, search, download, install, news
*/

so how to make it run for case-insensitive keys-'keywords' or 'Keywords' ??

Comment: Please read my answer again - as I've said all you ever need to use is (based on your example) `$all_meta['keywords'];` - this will work for *all* web sites that have meta keyword information present.

Comment: Also, if you're talking about making the keyword data itself lower case, simply use `$keywords = strtolower($all_meta['keywords']);`

Comment: According to the PHP docs, the name values should be converted into lower case as they are set as the keys: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php.  Are you certain that you occasionally get an upper case key?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're talking about as the 'keywords' index in the array returned from get_meta_tags isn't case sensitive in the manner you're describing.

As such, any keyword information that's been provided will be made available within this element.

e.g. If you look at the source of Microsoft.com you'll see...

```
<meta name="Keywords" content="Microsoft, product, support, help, training, Office, Windows, software, download, trial, preview, demo,  business, security, update, free, computer, PC, server, search, download, install, news" scheme="" />
```

...and if you run...

```
<?php
    $sourceURL = 'http://www.microsoft.com';
    $metaData = get_meta_tags($sourceURL);

    var_dump($metaData);
?>
```

... the 'keywords' element contains...

> ["keywords"]=>   string(192)
>   "Microsoft, product, support, help,
>   training, Office, Windows, software,
>   download, trial, preview, demo, 
>   business, security, update, free,
>   computer, PC, server, search,
>   download, install, news"

As such, get_meta_tags, etc. is doing the right thing and any keywords present in the page will always be available within the 'keywords' element.

**UPDATE**

If you're trying to get each of the keywords from within the meta keywords string into an array, you can use:

```
<?php
    $sourceURL = 'http://www.microsoft.com';
    $metaData = get_meta_tags($sourceURL);
    $keywords = explode(',', $metaData['keywords']);

    // Trim un-necessary leading/trailing spaces
    foreach($keywords as &$keyword) {
        $keyword = strtolower(trim($keyword));
    }

    var_dump($keywords);
?>
```

Simply remove the `strtolower` call from the above if you don't want the keywords to be lower-cased.

Comment: @middaparka
on seeing the website's source page(www.microsoft.com) from web-browser it shows 
<meta name="Keywords" content=...........>
as "Keywords" ...
but while displaying it using print_r($metaData['keywords'])-----only "keywords" work and not "Keywords"...

Comment: @user641086 That's precisely my point - PHP will always present the keywords array element in lower case. (i.e.: It will always be `keywords` irrespective of what the website uses.)

Comment: @middaparka but my question is how to get contents if website's meta is in "Keywords" or "keywords"....

Comment: my actual question is how to extract meta data's keywords...if the website contains meta keyword info then hw to extract it...i have tried the posted method-which does't fits the deal..can u tell me any modification or alternatives?

Comment: @user641086 Sorry, but I don't understand what's wrong with PHP's method as explained above. What do you want to do that it isn't doing?

Comment: @user641086 Are you trying to get each *keyword* from *within* `$metaData['keywords']` into an array? If so, see the update to my answer.

Comment: @middaparka -> +1 for the patience and still trying to help. Also an additional +1 for the point about the 'keywords' always being lowercase - I didn't know PHP did that.

Comment: @My Head Hurts Mucho ta. If Stack Overflow had a "perseverance" badge, I'd be due one soon. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could make all of the keys lowercase before searching:

```
array_change_key_case($all_meta, CASE_LOWER));
```

Comment: +1 I'm pretty sure there's absolutely no need for this, but your solution would certainly remove all doubt. :-)

Comment: @middaparka. Thanks. I really liked your answer, but I think that if there was more metadata, such as "description", then there would still be the same issue with not being able to extract the keywords without changing the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
$keyword_meta = array_keys( $all_meta );
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: thanks @benslu for suggesting...
but this wont help me...i need to derive values of array ["keywords"] which will be case-insensitive and not just keys....